# Wizz discount club - companions on different flight

Tags: air-travel, wizz-air

Wizz air state the following in their [discount club page](https://wizzair.com/en-gb/information-and-services/wizz-services/wizz-discount-club#/):

> "In order to have access to the discounts, the holder of the membership must be one of the passengers in the booking."

Does "booking" here mean the same flight or just the same order (with possibly one flight for the member and another for the companions)?

Comment: Can you even make one booking for different flights (not return) in a single booking? E.g. with Ryanair you can't - don't know but doubtful about Wizzair.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wizz Air has a simple booking system that only provides one-way flights. As you can't buy flights for different people on the same order it's pretty clear that for the discount to work both tickets need to be bought for the same flight in the same order.

Comment: Oh, I've never booked with them so I didn't know that... Thank you!

Comment: They do allow for return flights though, don't they?

Comment: @mts they consider each flight to be a separate flight, so the second leg (the return leg) is not contingent on the first leg (the outbound leg).  They might be sold together, but they arent classed as linked.